Conditional probability distribution of a random variable $X$ given $Y$
I am seeking for a general definition of the conditional probability distribution (or law) of a random variable $X$ given another random variable $Y$. The definitions that I have been able to find seem to assume the existence of probability density/mass functions.
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $(\mathcal{S}_1, \Sigma_1)$ a measurable space. Consider a random variable $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathcal{S}_1$. The distribution (or law) of $X$ is defined as the probability measure on $(\mathcal{S}_1, \Sigma_1)$ given by $P_X(S) = \mathbb{P}[X^{-1}(S)]$.
Similarly, let $(\mathcal{S}_2, \Sigma_2)$ be a measurable space and consider another random variable $Y: \Omega \rightarrow \mathcal{S}_2$. The joint law of $X$ and $Y$ is the probability measure given by $P_{X, Y} (S_1 \times S_2) = \mathbb{P}\left(X^{-1}(S_1) \cap Y^{-1}(S_2) \right) $.
Is it possible to write the conditional distribution $P_{X \mid Y}$ in terms of the distributions $P_X$, $P_Y$ and $P_{X,Y}$?
